# Render section with blocks use Section Rendering API

Tags: shopify, liquid

I use the Section Rendering API to render the content of a section but the problem is that it cannot render the blocks that the section owns.

Example:

```
<div class="section-blocks">
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        {%- case block.type -%}
            {%- when 'title' -%}
                <span>This is title</span>
            {%- when 'text' -%}
                <span>This is text</span>
        {%- endcase -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
</div>

{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Demo section",
    "tag": "section",
    "class": "demo-section",
    "settings": [],
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "title",
            "name": "the_title",
            "settings": []
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "name": "the_text",
            "settings": []
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Normally, it will display the following content:

```
<div class="section-blocks">
    <span>This is title</span>
    <span>This is text</span>
</div>
```

But when using Section Rendering API, the content is only:

```
<div class="section-blocks"></div>
```

Section Rendering API does not support rendering blocks?
Or did I miss a document or tutorial?

Can someone explain it to me, thanks!

Comment: Same issue here. Very odd there is nothing in the documentation about this.

Comment: Hi @Cook88, it's possible that there won't be a way to do that because of Shopify's limitations.
My issue here: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/1496

Answer (score -1):

You miss a lot.

1. Sections and blocks are parts of a theme that should be updated using the theme / customize at the Shopify admin panel.
2. You can use sections on any page based on a JSON template on your theme, you can add and remove sections.
3. The sections can contain blocks, blocks are the customizable part of a section. To activate/deactivate a block you should use customize on the admin panel.

with that, Sections are a nice way to give flexibility to the theme, and blocks are a nice way to do a section flexibly. Using sections and blocks made it easy to make changes on the look of the site without code knowledge using the visual editor on Customize.

Comment: Looks like you're misunderstanding what I mean.

I want to use Ajax (Section Rendering API) to get a content section ( which contains many blocks )

Doc: https://shopify.dev/api/section-rendering

Comment: Your result shows like you don't add any block to your section by the customize page on the admin panel.  my point 1. on the liquid file you declare the blocks type that the section can contain, but you need to add and fill the blocks you need on the customize page.